# parse set image javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am trying to set the image of a div. This code doesn't work:

```
    var myUrl=profilePhotoFile.url()
    var div=document.getElementById("vignette")
    console.log(div)
    div.style.content="url(profilePhotoFile.url()) no-repeat";
```

profilePhotoFile.url() returns a string, by the way

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to set image as a background .?

if yes

```
//var myUrl=profilePhotoFile.url()
//setting temp image URL
var myUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
var div = document.getElementById("vignette");
div.style.backgroundImage="url("+myUrl+")";
div.style.backgroundRepeat="repeat-y";
```

jsfiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/o0c6LLo0/1/

if yo want to set image in side vignette container

```
//var myUrl=profilePhotoFile.url()
//setting temp image URL
var myUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
var div = document.getElementById("vignette");
div.innerHTML="<img src="+myUrl+">";
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/o0c6LLo0/2/

Answer (score 0):

You likely mean

```
div.style.content="url("+profilePhotoFile.url()+") no-repeat";
```

However I do not think the no-repeat is used for content, normally it is for background-image